# How to solve this type of differential equation? please help.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have come across this differential equation :
[image]

It is not homogeneous. further, I have converted to this:
$$\left ( 2+3\frac{x}{v} \right )^2 = \frac{dv}{dx}-1$$
Where v=x+y-2
Next v=zx,
And finally reached:
$$\int \frac{dz}{\left ( -2+\frac{3}{z} \right )^2 +1-z}=\int \frac{dx}{x}$$
But can't solve after this.
Would you please help me to solve?

Comment: Well, you can in principle integrate the LHS away from the singularity at $z = 3/2$.  Because the RHS is just $\ln|x|$, from my perspective this looks like a solution, assuming you didn't make any typos along the way.

Comment: You have done it right, but perhaps the last $z$ integral is not doable.